# Getting Remainder/% operator Throwing Error in php

Tags: php

I am new to php and was doing some mathematics and found this weird thing happening.

```
$numOfDiffChars = 62;
$id = 285355773910;
$remainder = $id % $numOfDiffChars;
echo "Remainder: ".$remainder." ID: ".$id." NumOfElems: ".$numOfDiffChars."  ",($id - floor($id/$numOfDiffChars)*$numOfDiffChars);
```

The answer is as follows:
Remainder: 10 ID: 285355773910 NumOfElems: 62 26

which states that % operator gives the remainder 10 whereas mathematically its 26. What could be the reason for this? Is it just some error that I committed or is there a logic?

Comment: I know this isn't helpful, but this works correctly on PHP 5.3.3 on x64 Debian. It *could* be a 32-bit issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes its an issue with version try your code here. http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: i have tested you code its giving 26 only.

Comment: Yes in my system its giving 10. But when i tried online its showing 26. Hence its either php verison issue or 32-bit issue as Peulo said.

Comment: yeah it seems like a 32bit issue as Peulo said. It works fine on the given link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure, but if your using a 32-bit machine the problem could be that the integer `$id` is out of bound and therefore interpreted as a floating point.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `fmod` function find example on  --->
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php

Answer (score 1):

From php.net

Note that operator % (modulus) works just with integers (between -214748348 and 2147483647) while fmod() works with short and large numbers.